# Convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd using xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

First time I am using XSLT.
I need to convert date from dd/mm/yyyy  to yyyy-mm-dd .
Below are my codes.

```
<xsl:element name="transactionDate">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(col26,5,5), '-', substring(col26,3,1), '-', substring(col26,1,1))"/>
            </xsl:element>
```

In above code I am able to convert the date from dd/mm/yyyy  to yyyy-mm-dd  but when the date came as double digit then its not working.

Can somebody please suggest.

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

If `col26` contains a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, then your expression should be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(col26, 7, 4), '-', substring(col26, 4, 2), '-', substring(col26, 1, 2))"/>
```

Not sure what you mean by "when the date came as double digit". The above assumes that the days and months in the input are zero-padded to 2 digits each. Otherwise the format is **not** `dd/mm/yyyy`.

---

### Added:

> if the date is coming as 2/4/2019 then its (my code )working fine

If the date can be `2/4/2019` then your format is `d/m/y`, not `dd/mm/yyyy`. To convert it to `yyyy-mm-dd`, try:

```
<transactionDate>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-before(col26, '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring-before(substring-after(col26, '/'), '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring-after(substring-after(col26, '/'), '/')" />

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($y, '0000')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '-00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')" />
</transactionDate>
```

---

### Added #2:

> sorry to inform you that in date field the value is "20/12/2019 9:24:00 AM" ,time is also coming in csv

It is indeed regrettable that you did not reveal this information sooner.

If your input format is `d/m/y h:mm:ss xm`, then use:

```
<transactionDate>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before(col26, ' ')" />

    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-before($date, '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($y, '0000')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '-00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')" />
</transactionDate>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpU

Comment: yes .In csv file col26 is a date filed.  If the date is  coming as   2/4/2019 then its (my code  )working fine if the date is coming as 15/12/2019 then it is not coming as expected.Kindly help.

Comment: I tried your code but output is coming as <transactionDate>NaN-12-20</transactionDate>  .Here year is not coming as NaN and sorry to inform you that  in date field  the value is  "20/12/2019  9:24:00 AM" ,time is also coming in csv but I want output like 2019-12-20. Please help me out.

Comment: Well, for crying out loud, why not  tell us all that right from the start? Please show more consideration for the time of people that are trying to help you.